# How to remove delivery shipping step on prestashop 1.6.1?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to **prestashop** and I'm having major trouble removing  the delivery shipping step because I only sell virtual products. I am using prestashop 1.6.1.

I know I have to modify `order-carrier.tpl` file and have followed several posts here and there but couldn't get it done right.

Does any of you have any actual idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonjour, here is what i did


Override **AdminOrderPreferencesController** and add a boolean configuration field to toggle this functionnality

```
$this->fields_options = array(
    [...]
    'PS_ORDER_PROCESS_BYPASS_SHIPPING' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Bypass shipping step'),
        'hint' => $this->l('Do not show shipping step in order process.'),
        'validation' => 'isBool',
        'cast' => 'intval',
        'type' => 'bool'
    )
);
```

You can now find a toggle button in Backoffice under **Preferences > Orders**

Override **OrderController** and add an `if` in `init()` method to set the current step to *payment step* if the controller inits itself on *delivery step*

```
public function init()
{
    global $orderTotal;

    parent::init();

    $this->step = (int)Tools::getValue('step');

    // HERE IT IS
    if((bool)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_BYPASS_SHIPPING') && $this->step == self::STEP_DELIVERY){
        $this->step = self::STEP_PAYMENT;
    }

    if (!$this->nbProducts) {
        $this->step = -1;
    }
```

Also bypass the CGV checking verification on payment step in `initContent()` method.

If you don't, CGV will never be checked, it will redirect you on *delivery step*, you will tell him that he is in fact on *payment step*, he will check for CGV again, he will do the same redirection ... and you are in an infinite loop

```
case OrderController::STEP_PAYMENT:
    $cgv = Tools::getValue('cgv') || $this->context->cookie->check_cgv;

    if (
        !(bool)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_BYPASS_SHIPPING') && // HERE IT IS
        $is_advanced_payment_api === false && Configuration::get('PS_CONDITIONS')
        && (!Validate::isBool($cgv) || $cgv == false)
    ) {
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=2');
    }
```

Pass the configuration parameter to the view to modify display

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('bypass_shipping_step', (bool)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_BYPASS_SHIPPING'));
```

And in your views, do you styling stuff with some `if`
In **order-steps.tpl** you can add an `{if not $bypass_shipping_step}...{/if}` around the fourth `li` to hide it, and do something like :

```
{if $bypass_shipping_step}
<style>
    ul.step li{
        width:25%;
    }
</style>
{/if}
```

or import a dedicated stylesheet which would be cleaner.



Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for this. it really helps. To those who's asking where the smarty assign should be placed, I placed it at the end of init() method in OrderController.php.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228469/how-to-remove-delivery-shipping-step-on-prestashop-1-7/48859854#48859854 for 1.7 version

Comment: This only works when customer is logged in. How about for new members?

Answer (score 1):

In shopping-cart.tpl, remove call to order-carrier.tpl. If you are not using one pagecheckout, in orderController.php, you have to change all redirection to step 2 (shipping method choosing), to redirection step 3 Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=2'); to Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=3');