# How to remove delivery shipping step on prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

In reference to:
[How to remove delivery shipping step on prestashop 1.6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475736/how-to-remove-delivery-shipping-step-on-prestashop-1-6-1)

I am looking for a solution for Prestashop v1.7.2.4, any ideas? 
I tried to comment some code lines but it created extra problem like not submitting the order
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to hide Address step by assigning all orders to a single Address and removing the Address step from checkout process. Let's say you have an address with id = 2, using code below, all orders will be created with this address.

**1.** Create an address from BO, let's say it has `id_address` = 2

**2.** Hook actionDispatcher to update our cart in database

and hook your module to actionDispatcher

`modules/yourmodule/yourmodule.php`

```php
    <?php
    public function hookActionDispatcher($params = []){
      // every time we go to a payment controller, we update current cart id_addresses to 2
      $payments_controllers = [
        'ps_wirepaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
        'ps_checkpaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
      ];
      if($params['controller_type'] == Dispatcher::FC_FRONT &&
        in_array($params['controller_class'], $payments_controllers) &&
        $params['is_module']){

        $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
        if($cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice){
          $cart->id_address_delivery = 2;
          $cart->id_address_invoice = 2;
          $cart->update();
        }
      }
    }
```

**3.** Override Address with hardcoded id_address

`override/classes/Address.php`

```php
    class Address extends AddressCore {
      public static function getFirstCustomerAddressId($id_customer, $active = true){
        return 2; // hardcoded id_address
      }
    }
```

**4.** Override Cart to have an always valid address

`override/classes/Cart.php`

```php
    class Cart extends CartCore {
      public function checkAndUpdateAddresses(){
        return true; // always valid
      }
    }
```

**5.** Override OrderController to remove Adress step from checkout

`override/controllers/front/OrderController.php`

```php
    class OrderController extends OrderControllerCore {
      protected function bootstrap(){
        // copy everything from https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.2.x/controllers/front/OrderController.php#L90
        // but comment those lines:
        // ->addStep(new CheckoutAddressesStep(
        //     $this->context,
        //     $translator,
        //     $this->makeAddressForm()
        // ))
      }
    }
```

Address step is now hidden from the front office :
[image: no address]
[image: confirmed]

If you only do step 5, you will be redirected to `checkout?step=1` because ps_wirepayment do a check on `cart->id_address` at validation:

`modules/ps_wirepayment/controllers/front/validation.php`

```php
    if ($cart->id_customer == 0 || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0 || !$this->module->active){
      Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');
    }
```

Cheers,

Florian

Answer (score 1):

On prestashop 1.7.* I managed to disable (make disappear) the whole delivery step. In my scenario, the business model for my customer is Cash on delivery.

To achieve that I commented it out in the source code.

in the file

```
controllers/front/OrderController.php
comment out checkoutDeliveryStep
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply comment out the following lines

```
->addStep(new CheckoutAddressesStep(
            $this->context,
            $translator,
            $this->makeAddressForm()
        ));
```

in /controllers/front/OrderController.php

Comment: Sorry this breaks the checkout process for some payment providers.