# How to remove delivery shipping step on prestashop 8.1?

Tags: prestashop

In reference to: [How to remove delivery shipping step on prestashop 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228469/how-to-remove-delivery-shipping-step-on-prestashop-1-7)

I want to completely disable the address step from the checkout order process, since I'm selling only digital products and not interessted in knowing costumers addresses

[image]

I overwritten as in the answer in Address.php and Cart.php and OrderController.php but I get only a blank page

1. Create an address from BO, let's say it has id_address = 2
2. Hook actionDispatcher to update our cart in database

and hook your module to actionDispatcher

modules/yourmodule/yourmodule.php

```
<?php
public function hookActionDispatcher($params = []){
  // every time we go to a payment controller, we update current cart id_addresses to 2
  $payments_controllers = [
    'ps_wirepaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
    'ps_checkpaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
  ];
  if($params['controller_type'] == Dispatcher::FC_FRONT &&
    in_array($params['controller_class'], $payments_controllers) &&
    $params['is_module']){

    $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
    if($cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice){
      $cart->id_address_delivery = 2;
      $cart->id_address_invoice = 2;
      $cart->update();
    }
  }
}
```

3. Override Address with hardcoded id_address

override/classes/Address.php

```
class Address extends AddressCore {
  public static function getFirstCustomerAddressId($id_customer, $active = true){
    return 2; // hardcoded id_address
  }
}
```

4. Override Cart to have an always valid address

override/classes/Cart.php

```
class Cart extends CartCore {
  public function checkAndUpdateAddresses(){
    return true; // always valid
  }
}
```

5. Override OrderController to remove Adress step from checkout

override/controllers/front/OrderController.php

```
class OrderController extends OrderControllerCore {
  protected function bootstrap(){
    // copy everything from https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.2.x/controllers/front/OrderController.php#L90
    // but comment those lines:
    // ->addStep(new CheckoutAddressesStep(
    //     $this->context,
    //     $translator,
    //     $this->makeAddressForm()
    // ))
  }
}
```